# (Python) How to modify tuples in a tuple

Tags: python, sql, list, tuples, converters

I do a fetchall to have the value of my database, but I have a problem.

The fetchall return me a tuple :

```
((25, 'Bonzon', 'Julien', '0642181185', 25), (1, 'BLOQUIAU', 'Thomas', '0669696969', None), (2, 'PARAT', 'Clement', '0669696969', None), (3, 'FOUCAUD', 'Enzo', '0669696969', None), (4, 'JEAN', 'Alexandre', '0678787878', None), (23, 'Bal', 'Hugo', '0642181185', None), (24, 'Gerez', 'Quentin', '0642181185', None))
```

However, , in a tuple we can't modify directly a value. 
I could find solutions to convert the tuple to list, modify the value and return to tuple.

```
[(25, 'Bonzon', 'Julien', '0642181185', 25), (1, 'BLOQUIAU', 'Thomas', '0669696969', None), (2, 'PARAT', 'Clement', '0669696969', None), (3, 'FOUCAUD', 'Enzo', '0669696969', None), (4, 'JEAN', 'Alexandre', '0678787878', None), (23, 'Bal', 'Hugo', '0642181185', None), (24, 'Gerez', 'Quentin', '0642181185', None)]
```

The problem is that when I do this, I can do this, but I have tuples in my tuple. And I don't know how to modify the tuples in the main tuple

Any helps to resolve my problem ?

Best regards

Comment: Where are you stuck?  It is the same process, but one level deeper.  You have to convert the tuple to a mutable type -- list is the closest cognate -- make your change, and convert back to a tuple.

Comment: If you need to make frequent changes, why are you storing your values in a tuple at all?

Comment: I don't need to do many changes, it's the only one change i do. ``` list = cur.fetchall() ``` from pymysql storing my list in tuple value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a tuple.

You have to transform all to lists then modify them.

Consider this example :

```
t = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
l = [list(e) for e in t]     # [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
# < ---  modify l --- >
n = [ tuple(e) for e in l]   # [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
n = (*n,)                    # ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Comment: Why you do this ? ``` n = (*n,) ```

Comment: To tansform the list into a tuple.

Comment: @uPong I updated my answer. I added comments to explain more my code.

Comment: Hum ok thank you ! I think you have fully answered my question and that I will be released to continue my project.

Comment: Thank you and i do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily convert your tuples in lists like this:

```py
# I think this is the first thing you did
myList = list(myTuple)

# Additionally to convert your inside tuples into a list you could do:
myList = [list(t) for t in myList]
```

Comment: You can do this in one line, as I did

Comment: Hello ! I have an error when i call my tuple. Why ? http://prntscr.com/rlhkmh

Comment: @uPong check my answer. I gave you an example clear and working.

Comment: @ThunderPheonix i answered you

Comment: It is because you named your list "list", and the list is a reserved word in Python. Substitute your variable "list" with another name.

Comment: Instead of ```list = cur.fetchall()``` use ```myList = cur.fetchall()```